# Headphone noise when no sound is played

Tags: 12.04, alsa, soundcard, noise, hda-intel

I have an Asus K50IJ laptop with ubuntu 12.04 on it, and with the following hardware:
after typing:  `sudo aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: VT1708S Analog [VT1708S Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 2: VT1708S Alt Analog [VT1708S Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

My codec called: `VIA VT1708S`

Every time when a sound is played, I hear an annoying noise, similar to white noise. The worst part is that it doesn't stop after the sound is over. I googled for it thousands of times, tried every setup of alsamixer, but nothing works. I found on a forum, that because of the integrated soundcard on the motherboard, it may be the static earth noise from the electric network. I removed my laptop charger (from the laptop) and after 2-3 seconds the sound just stopped. When I plugged it back, it doesn't come back until I play another sound.

Comment: So, this is a hardware issue... actually most of times, noise is a hardware issue...

Comment: But when I plug the charger back in to the laptop, it doesn't start again. Isn't it possible, that this is some hardware noise filter issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same issue and it seems to be known. I've found this during my researches: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1252733 .

Apparently a fix has been made but don't know when it will be available and how we can apply it for testing. (the fix: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/tiwai/sound.git/commit/?id=493a52a9b6645f61954580c7d4bd52fa62110934)